# How to solve stack memory problems?

Tags: java, android

iam trying to build an android app which makes users to do some calculation in a time limit. The code worked well until i divided the code into two parts and created another class for doing other task .

I have imported all the corressponding packages and class files to the new class .There were no errors in the code but when i run the app it crashes .I tried changing the code many times but no use. Code works well when i combine all the code into a single class.

the error i get is "java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB on line number  "

```
        **MainActivity.java**



                        package e.nani.firstattempt;

                        import android.content.Context;
                        import android.os.AsyncTask;
                        import android.os.Bundle;
                        import android.os.CountDownTimer;
                        import android.os.Vibrator;
                        import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
                        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
                        import android.util.Log;
                        import android.view.View;
                        import android.widget.Button;
                        import android.widget.TextView;
                        import android.widget.Toast;



                        import java.util.Random;

                        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
                        public int a1;//random num 1
                        public int a2;//random num 2;
                        public   TextView textview;
                        public Button b1;
                        public Button b2;
                        public   Button b3;
                        public Button b4;
                        public int option1;
                        public int option2;
                        public   int option3;
                        public   int option4;
                        public int score=0;
                        TextView scoreid;
                        int numberofquestions=10;
                        TextView time;
                        public   int answers[]=new int[4];
                       Logic  c=new Logic();

                        @Override
                        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                        textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sum);
                        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.option1);
                        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.option2);
                        b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.option3);
                        b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.option4);
                        time=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);

                        scoreid=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreid) ;
                        scoreid.setText((0+"/"+numberofquestions));


                        c.operatio();

                        timer.start();

                        }


                        public void operation(View V)
                        {
                        try{
                        switch(V.getId()) {
                        case R.id.option1:

                        if (b1.getText().equals(Integer.toString(option4))) {
                        score = score + 1;
                             c.operatio();
                        scoreid.setText((score +"/"+ numberofquestions));
                        } else {

                        Toast.makeText(this, "wrong answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Vibrator vibrator=(Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        vibrator.vibrate(500);
                        c.operatio();
                        }
                        break;
                        case R.id.option2:


                        if (b2.getText().equals(Integer.toString(option4))) {
                        score = score + 1;
                        c.operatio();
                        scoreid.setText(score+"/"+ numberofquestions);
                        } else
                        {

                        Toast.makeText(this, "wrong answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Vibrator vibrator=(Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        vibrator.vibrate(500);
                        c.operatio();
                        }
                        break;
                        case R.id.option3:
                        if (b3.getText().equals(Integer.toString(option4))) {
                        score = score + 1;
                        c.operatio();
                        scoreid.setText((score+"/"+ numberofquestions));
                        } else
                        {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "wrong answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Vibrator vibrator=(Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        vibrator.vibrate(500);
                        c.operatio();
                        }
                        break;

                        case R.id.option4:
                        if (b4.getText().equals(Integer.toString(option4))) {
                        score = score + 1;
                        c.operatio();
                        scoreid.setText(score+"/"+ numberofquestions);
                        } else
                        {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "wrong answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Vibrator vibrator=(Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        vibrator.vibrate(500);
                        c.operatio();
                        }

                        break;
                        }



                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        }





                        CountDownTimer timer=new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        time.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                        }

                        public void onFinish() {
                        time.setText("done!");
                        }
                        };


                        }
```

**Logic.java**

```
                         package e.nani.firstattempt;
                        import java.util.Random;

                        class Logic {
                            MainActivity s=new MainActivity();
                            public void operatio() {
                                try {
                                        Random n = new Random();
                                        int n1 = n.nextInt(4);
                                        int n2 = n.nextInt(4);
                                        int n3 = n.nextInt(4);
                                        int n4 = n.nextInt(4);

                                        s.a1 = n.nextInt(51);
                                        s.a2 = n.nextInt(35);
                                        s.option1 = n.nextInt((s.a1 + s.a2) + 1);

                                        s.option2 = n.nextInt((s.a1 + s.a2) + 1);
                                        s.option3 = n.nextInt((s.a1 + s.a2) + 1);
                                        s.option4 = s.a1 + s.a2;


                                        s.answers[n1] = s.option1;
                                        while (n2 == n1) {
                                            n2 = n.nextInt(4);
                                        }
                                        while (s.option2 == s.option1 || s.option2 == s.option4) {

                                            s.option2 = n.nextInt((s.a1 + s.a2) + 1);

                                        }


                                        s.answers[n2] = s.option2;
                                        while (s.option3 == s.option2 || s.option3 == s.option1 || s.option3 == s.option4)


                                        {
                                            s.option3 = n.nextInt((s.a1 + s.a2) + 1);
                                        }


                                        while (n3 == n2 || n3 == n1)

                                        {
                                            n3 = n.nextInt(4);
                                        }

                                        s.answers[n3] = s.option3;

                                        while (n4 == n2 || n4 == n1 || n4 == n3) {
                                            n4 = n.nextInt(4);
                                        }
                                        s.answers[n4] = s.option4;


                                        s.b1.setText(Integer.toString(s.answers[0]));
                                        s.b2.setText(Integer.toString(s.answers[1]));
                                        s.b3.setText(Integer.toString(s.answers[2]));
                                        s.b4.setText(Integer.toString(s.answers[3]));
                                        s.textview.setText(s.a1 + "+" + s.a2);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

The main question here is ,why is the app working fine when the code is only in main class but not working when some code is written in other class ?
ThankYou.

Comment: What is the exact error with trace?

Comment: **java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB on line number 37** ...This is the main error @Carcigenicate

Comment: The two methods are mutually recursive without termination; the rest should be obvious?

Comment: Yeah i fixed it . But now this line  ** " s.b1.setText(Integer.toString(s.answers[0]));" ** has an error .The error is that there is a nullpointer exception from this line in Login class .the error reads "attempt to invoke a virtual method **"s.b1.setText(Integer.toString(s.answers[0]))"** ".Can someone help me with it .Thankyou.@another-dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MainActivity you have a variable c with type Logic which is instantiated.
But in your Logic class has MainActivity type variable which try to instantiate MainActivity class. In a nutshell in a class A you instantiate class B which instatieates class A and so on...
By the way you cannot instantiate AppCompatActivity classes directly. 
So remove `MainActivity s=new MainActivity();` in your Logic.class.

Hope I could help you.

Comment: Thankyou ,thats a nice explaination. How do i access values of variables declared in MainActivity.java without instantiating it ? Should i extend MainActivity from Logic class or is there any other way ? @Csongi77

Comment: The only purpose and responsibility of MainActivity is displaying values (texts, images etc.) You should make a ViewModel which contains logic and input values entered in MainActivity. In this case you won't lost values when your Activity is destroyed (for example in case of incoming call, rotating device from portrait to landscape etc). In a nutshell, put logic into ViewModel separated from Activity. For more info about Activity lifecycle, ViewModel class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity , https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel